# Read and write on single socket in java

Tags: java, spring, sockets, serversocket

I have a socket server which accepts only one client socket connection. It will remember the connection and send response on the same. If client opens one more  connection to the server with same host and port, then server will accept it but send response on last remembered socket connection. I don't know how server is able to do it as it is not in my control.

Below is code i tried. In my code, I am first creating Socket connection with server and storing it in Spring application context. For every request, I am getting it and using Input and Output Stream.

I am able to send one request and receive one response. But when i send second request, I do not get any response from server.

Please make a note that, server sends message length in first two bytes and appends the rest of the response.

For second response, I get header as `0000` and response as `null`.

Can somebody point me to example where client is creating only one socket with server and use its input and output stream for every request. Below is code i tried.

SocketConnector.java

```
public class SocketConnector {

    LoggerUtil log = LoggerUtil.getInstance();
    final String className = "SocketConnector";

    @Value("${socket.host}")
    String socketHost;

    @Value("${socket.port}")
    int socketPort;

    @Value("${socket.connection.timeout}")
    int socketConnectionTimeout;

    @Value("${socket.read.timeout}")
    int socketReadTimeout;

    @Bean
    Socket socketSocket(){
        Socket s = new Socket();
        final String methodName = "socketSocket";
        try {
            s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(socketHost, socketPort), socketConnectionTimeout); // Connection timeout set to 5 seconds with socket.
            s.setSoTimeout(socketReadTimeout); // Read timeout set to 2 seconds. This means socket should send response in maximum of 2 second for every request.
            log.doLog(3, className, methodName, "Created Socket Connection");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.doLog(3, className, methodName, LoggerUtil.getExStackTrace(e));
        } 
        return s;
    };
}
```

LogonScheduler.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class LogonScheduler {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("socketSocket")
    private Socket socketSocket;

    private DataInputStream socketInputStream;
    private OutputStream socketOutputStream;

    static LoggerUtil log = LoggerUtil.getInstance();

    final static String className = "LogonScheduler";
    String logonResponse = null;

    byte[] reqMsg = null;
    byte[] msgLen = null;
    byte[] header = null;
    byte[] buf = null;
    byte[] response = null;

    int messageLen = -1;

    /*@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 17500)*/
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void logonSender(){
        final String methodName = "logonSender";
        try {
            socketInputStream = new DataInputStream(socketSocket.getInputStream());
            socketOutputStream = socketSocket.getOutputStream();

            /*
            * Created a byte array named buf and writing to socketOutputStream
            * buf = createRequest();
            */

            socketOutputStream.write(buf);

            header = new byte[2];
            socketInputStream.read(header, 0, 2);

            messageLen = Integer.parseInt(bytetoHex(header), 16);
            log.doLog(4, className, methodName, "Message length received :" + messageLen);

            logonResponse = bytetoHex(header);
            response = new byte[messageLen];
            socketInputStream.readFully(response, 0, messageLen);

            logonResponse += bytetoHex(response);

            log.doLog(4, className, methodName, "Response Message with header : " + logonResponse);
            logonResponse = logonResponse.substring(4);
            log.doLog(4, className, methodName, "Response Message without header : " + logonResponse);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            Utils.closeResources(logonResponse, reqMsg, msgLen, header, buf, response, messageLen);
        }
    }

    public String bytetoHex(byte[] b) {
        if (isEmpty(b)) {
            return null;
        }

        String hex = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            hex += byteToHex(b[i]);
        }

        return hex;
    }

    // Returns hex String representation of byte b
    public String byteToHex(byte b) {
        char[] array = {hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f]};
        return new String(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `socketInputStream.read(header, 0, 2);` to use `readFully`.

Comment: That doesn’t help me